# Android: Trigger unhover on link

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

If a link in android is clicked and has e.preventDefault() attached to it, it will still remain hovered after the click. Is it possible to trigger unhover?

Doesn't work:

```
$('testElement').on('touchend', function () {
  $(this).trigger('mouseout');
});
```